# Как реализовать парсер Markdown?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Смысл задания:
Преобразовать строки, содержащие определенные символы. Использовать регулярные выражения.

1. Header - Строка, которая начинается с #, ##, ### и т.д. является заголовком. Данные строки должны оборачиваться тегами `<h1></h1>`, `<h2></h2>`, `<h3></h3>` и т.д.
2. Простая строка должна оборачиваться тегом `<p></p>`;
3. Если в строке встречается * ... * то тогда обернуть в тег `<strong></strong>` и т.д.

Пример:

### Header line

Simple * line * with strong
Line with link [Link to google](h ttps://www.google.com) in center...

Результат преобразования:

```
< html>
  < body>
      <h2>Header line</h2>
      <p>Simple < strong>line< /strong> with strong</p>
      <p>Line with link <a href="https://www.google.com">Link to google</a> in center</p>
      <!--...--> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы сами пытались сделать что-то, как спросить на форуме?

Comment: Смог составить регулярные выражения для поиска нужных элементов. А вот с заменой справиться пока не получается.

Comment: Приложите тогда к своему вопросу все то, что у вас получилось.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотеками - [pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown) либо [txtmark](https://github.com/rjeschke/txtmark). Это не насколько тривиальная задача, что бы отказываться от готовых библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Благодаря Вашему совету удалось разобраться с работой библиотек и выполнить задание